# Rewrite Subdomain As A Different Subdomain + Sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do this.

I have Only Office Cloud Version(SaaS). The domain to access it looks like this: `mydomain.onlyfoffice.com`.

It has a feature to apply a custom domain, so I changed it to: `desk.mydomain.com` by adjusting the setting in the onlyoffice control panel and I had to change the A record to a CNAME of `intranet.onlyoffice.com`. I can now access it by going to `desk.mydomain.com`.

Now here's my problem. How I can I make the URL look like this: `office.mydomain.com/desk/` ? I also need it to carry on with the URL's, like `office.mydomain.com/desk/app/etc/etc...`

Is this possible?

The reason for this setup is because I'm trying to organize all of my applications that I use for my business under one sub-domain: `office.mydomain.com`. I have other, non-saas applications installed in other sub-directories like: `office.mydomain.com/code/` and `office.mydomain.com/analytics/` and etc.

Since I cannot set the custom domain for onlyoffice to a subdomain + directory, I was thinking of setting it to a different sub-domain, then use mod_rewrite or a proxy pass or something to re-write the url.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with `mod_rewrite`.

I believe you are looking for the `ProxyPass` directive. First you need to enable `mod_proxy` and `proxy_http`, something like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

You should also add something for access:

```
<Proxy *.>
    # If using Apache 2.4, replace the next 2 lines with 'Require all granted', without quotes
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Proxy>
```

Then you need to add this to your `apache2.conf` (or `httpd.conf`) file (you can't do it from `.htaccess`):

```
ProxyPass     /desk/     http://www.desk.mydomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /desk/  http://www.desk.mydomain.com/
```

The first line enables the proxy (which is almost like a rewrite), and the `ProxyPassReverse` is essentially so that headers sent to the browser don't use `http://www.desk.mydomain.com`.

Don't forget to restart apache after enabling the modules and making the configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with rewrite + proxy module. Make sure you have rewrite, proxy and proxy_http module are activated. Then in the .htaccess file of office.mydomain.com use

```
RewriteRule ^desk/(.*) http://desk.mydomain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

This should do the trick.